# cannot resolve symbol 'assertDoesNotThrow'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have some problem with In `intellij`. I try to import the following library:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
```

But I get the following error:

```
cannot resolve symbol 'assertDoesNotThrow'
```

But I don't get errors for `assertEquals`.

The use:

```
assertDoesNotThrow(() -> r1.rate(new Pro(1, "xyz"), 0));
assertDoesNotThrow(() -> r1.rate(new Pro(1, "xyz"), 5));
```

I guess this is some problem with `JUInt`, but I can't seem to find the solution. I have tried some previous threads but without success.

Comment: What version of JUnit are you using? The `assertDoesNotThrow` methods were added in version `5.2`.

Comment: @Slaw how should I check?

Comment: How did you declare the dependency?

Comment: It just asked me to press `Alt+Enter` (new to intellij).

Comment: I think I'm using the Intellij library (no maven or grandle for sure).

Answer (score 1):

When you add JUnit library in IntelliJ IDEA via the intention action, there is a choice which library version to add:

[image: junit 5.3]

If you add 5.3 version, you will see the following in the [Module Dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies):

[image: module dependencies]

In case you have some older version there, delete these libraries and add the correct version again.

Refer to the [Configuring Testing Libraries](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-testing-libraries.html) help section.